# Laravel, converting data from raw query to JSON

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Hy all, can anyone help me with converting some data which will be return from model(based on the RAW query) into JSON.

So in my controller i have something like:

```
public function get_index() {
    $data = Something::getDataFromRawQuery();

    return View::make('....')->with('data', $data);
}
```

So my question is how to forward JSON data to the view from controller?

Here is the query:

```
$apps = DB::query('SELECT a.name,
    a.desc,
    a.sig,
    ar.rate
    FROM something a
    INNER JOIN something_else ar
    ON (a.id=ar.something_id)
    ORDER BY ar.rate DESC'
 );

 return $apps;
```

Comment: If it's not Fluent or Eloquent, then what is it? mysqli? PDO? Can you show us the code doing the query?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you shunning the Fluent Query Builder?

Comment: @JosephSilber there are some things that are awkward with the query builder; although this query doesn't look like it would be.

Comment: @PhillSparks - which is why I said *shunning*. Everything has its place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`DB::query` returns a simple array, so just call `json_encode` directly on it:

```
$data = Something::getDataFromRawQuery();

return View::make('....')->with('data', json_encode($data));
```

Comment: Getting error: Call to a member function to_array() on a non-object when use to_array()

Comment: After that in .js, var data = <?php echo json_decode($data) ?>;
i get following:

Error rendering view: [something::template]
Array to string conversion

Comment: Why are you `json_decode`ing it? Just do `var data = <?php echo $data; ?>;` and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `json_encode()`

```
public function get_index() {
    $data = Something::getDataFromRawQuery();

    /* Do your loop here to build an array "results" from $data, if necessary
       Really depends on what ::getDataFromRawQuery returns. */

    return View::make('....')->with('data', json_encode($results));
}
```