# How do you convert Laravel query results to json?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query that I call with:

```
$query = "select * from myTable";
$results = DB::connection('myDB')->select($query);
```

I want to be able to get this in the simple json format of:

```
[{firstColumn: firstColumnValue, secondColumn: secondColumnValue},
{firstColumn: firstColumnValue, secondColumn: secondColumnValue}]
```

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: the `$results` variable is actually an `StdClass`. You can directly use the `Response::json` facade as well if you need to directly send the data as a response.

Answer (score 4):

As I have read here : [Laravel, converting data from raw query to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16638154/laravel-converting-data-from-raw-query-to-json)
you can just use the json_encode. Hope that one helps.

Comment: It doesn't work? What's the output upon trying that? Can I see

Comment: Great! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you thought of writing web service or something related to it, then

```
$Response = array('success' => '1', 'result' => $yourData);
else
$Response = array('success' => '0', 'error' => 'Your Custom Errors');
return json_encode($Response);
```

So that you can handle it in while you retrieve according to the result.